JsonPath evaluates to array but need string in response
I'm evaluating some JsonPath to find a single value, and the result is coming back as an array, but I need it to give a string value.
I have the following data
{
    "id": 111,
    "name": "abc",
    "collectorDescription": "abc xyz",
    "customProperties": [
        {
            "name": "this.id",
            "value": "49271"
        },
        {
            "name": "this.Interval",
            "value": "30"
        },
        {
            "name": "this.categories",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "upTimeInSeconds": 0,
    "deletedTimeInMs": 0
}

And the JsonPath I am using to get the value of "this.id" is,
$.customProperties[?(@.name == 'this.id')].value

Which will give the response in array,
[
  "49271"
]

But I am looking to get response in String like
"49271"

I have tried the following combinations but they did not work.
$.customProperties[:1][?(@.name == 'this.id')].value
$.customProperties[0][?(@.name == 'this.id')].value
$.customProperties[?(@.name == 'this.id')].value[0] ... etc


Where are you running this JSONPath? The array wrapper may be being added by the library / tool, not by the JSONPath expression itself.

JSON Path is a querying syntax.  It's going to give you back a collection of results.  Represented in JSON, this will ALWAYS be an array.

@gregsdennis Not necessarily - that's why asked about the calling context. For instance, PostgreSQL's JSON functions include jsonb_path_query to get the results as a set and jsonb_path_query_array to get a JSON array; but also jsonb_path_exists and jsonb_path_match which return a boolean; and jsonb_path_query_first to get a single JSON value.
